# Reroute LAN HTTP traffic to node.js proxy using iptables

Tags: iptables, node.js

I'm trying to redirect all http traffic generated in my LAN to a node.js proxy running on a specific machine.

I'm using: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:8080`

(Testing one source machine at the moment. The proxy is on 192.168.1.2:8080). Unfortunately the traffic doesn't make it to the proxy. I can see the packet counter incrementing on the rule, and if I add another rule to LOG, I can see the log entries for http traffic from the 192.168.1.3 machine.

The proxy, however, doesn't get the traffic. I have it set to log requests connections, and I'm seeing nothing at all. If I have the browser use 192.168.1.2:8080 as the proxy, it works just fine.

The node.js proxy is a simple transparent proxy that randomly redirects traffic.

```
var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var net = require('net');

var redirect_host = url.parse(redirect_url).host;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var urlObj = url.parse(req.url);
  var target = urlObj.protocol + "//" + urlObj.host;

  if (Math.random() > redirect_chance || urlObj.host == redirect_host) {
      var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
      proxy.on("error", function (err, req, res) {
        console.log("proxy error", err);
        res.end();
      });
      console.log("Not redirecting " + target);
      proxy.web(req, res, {target: target});
  }
  else {
    console.log("Redirecting " + target + " to", redirect_url);
    res.writeHead(302, {'Location': redirect_url});
    res.end();
  }

}).listen(8080);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Tried adding the following rule: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 -d 192.168.1.2 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.1`, and it doesn't work. Well, not exactly. I see the following packets with this rule added, when I make an http request from the client:

(Gateway: 192.168.1.1, Proxy Server: 192.168.1.2, Client: 192.168.1.3)

```
SYN from Gateway to Proxy Server
SYN+ACK from Proxy Server to Gateway
ACK from Gateway to Proxy Server
HTTP Request from Client to Proxy Server
```

I'm not sure why the HTTP Request is not also being SNAT'd... or if that matters (I'm guessing not).

Next, I see continuous retransmission of the HTTP Request from Client to Proxy Server. From what I can tell its because the proxy server never sends an ACK. When I cancel the request in the browser, the client retransmits, but this time with ACK+FIN, causing the proxy server to ACK and send the response (both to the gateway, not the client). This is probably an issue with the proxy server, though possibly it's because it's getting the http request from an unexpected source?

iptables: http://pastebin.com/FvNq1Dyf

tcpdump: http://pastebin.com/zMBj10Qj

Answer (score 2):

You did set up only a half of rules for the proper packet flow. What your rule does, it changes the destination address upon packet's entry to iptables gateway.

Next, this packet is forwarded to your proxy, but it's source IP remains the same. So your proxy thinks it receives TCP SYN request from the client machine, and responds to it directly, but as the client did not open this connection SYN+ACK gets dropped. You can verify this with Wireshark and tcpdump.

To alleviate this you should add a rule into `POSTROUTING` that would also perform an `SNAT` changing your client's source IP to that one of iptables gateway. Something along these lines (I assume your iptables gateway IP is 192.168.1.1):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 -d 192.168.1.2 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: So I tried this, and it still doesn't quite work, though now it might be because of the proxy, not the routing. Can you tell me why all of the syn/ack packets get SNAT'd but not the actual HTTP request? Is this correct flow? (See post edits)

Comment: Could you please post a tcpdump output from the proxy machine and your complete iptables configuration? From your edits your packet flow is looking good except the last bit.

Comment: tcpdump: pastebin.com/zMBj10Qj

iptables: pastebin.com/FvNq1Dyf

Thanks for the help!